# Drone confiscated in Prague as tourist

Tags: drones, czech-republic

My hobbyist drone, a Parrot ANAFI, was caught while flying in a park in Prague. I had to file a police report. What is the offense and fine? How to best get help? I'm a tourist in Prague.

Comment: Are you from the EU?  Are you registered as a drone operator in the Czech Republic or in another EU country?

Answer (score 4):

Prague is **restricted airspace** and partially **no fly**. [Czech Aviation Authority](https://www.caa.cz/en/flight-operations/unmanned-aircraft/) says:

> The zones can be seen on the following website:
> https://dronview.rlp.cz/. Operation of unmanned aircraft in Prague for
> example would most probably collide with LKR9 Restricted Area (area
> covering most of Prague) and possibly with LKP1 Prohibited Area (area
> around Prague Castle, Charles Bridge, Vltava river), and currently
> LKP-CENTRUM, a Prohibited Area temporarily established in connection
> with the Czech presidency of the Council of the European Union.

https://dronview.rlp.cz/ for Prague:
[image]